# Facebook Like button Issue on the Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have added a facebook like button to my website. I am able to see a like button on the webiste. However when I click the like button, the like count increases but I receive a 401 authorisation required error in the pop up.

On reading facebook documentation further on facebook scrape url. I went to Object debugger and debugged the home page of my website.
When I clicked the link for scrape url I get this message 
"document returned no data"

When I clicked the graph api link, I get this as the ouput.

{
   "id": "id_nos",
   "url": "http://sitename.com /",
   "type": "website",
   "updated_time": "2014-03-06T04:30:13+0000",
   "created_time": "2014-03-04T06:58:54+0000",
   "is_scraped": false
}

Can anyone tell me, how I am suppose to handle this error. What steps I will have to take to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance

---

Updated the code for like button:

```
<div class="like-box">
    <div class="fb-like"
        data-href="<?php echo $poll['short_url']; ?>"
        data-send="false"
        data-layout="button_count"
        data-width="20" data-show-faces="false">
    </div></div>
```

The script is :

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

---

Update 2:

The site is protected and asks for username and password (Http authentication). Could this be the reason?

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to add the button?

Comment: @Seano666 I have updated the question with  the code for like button.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook needs to access your site in order to retrieve the [Open Graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#tags). If your site is protected with HTTP authentication Facebook cannot do so, and so like/share operations won't work correctly.